# Как воспроизвести гифку во время выполнения основного потока?

Tags: python, pyqt5, многопоточность, qthread, qmovie

Мне нужно во время выполнения функции `osnova()` воспроизводить гифку. 
А когда прекращается выполнение функции завершить воспроизведение гифки.

Набросал такой код, но не могу понять, что дальше?

````py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import sys, time, requests


class SomeThread(QThread):
  progressed = pyqtSignal(int)
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def run(self):
    for i in range(1, 6):
      self.progressed.emit(i)
      time.sleep(1)


class App(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Потоки")
    self.setFixedSize(900, 500)
    self.pBar = QProgressBar(self)
    self.pBar.setMaximum(5)
    self.pBar.setGeometry(0, 30, 300, 40)
    self.button = QPushButton("Start", self)
    self.movie_screen = QLabel("===================", self)
    self.movie_screen.setGeometry(5, 50, 500, 500)
    self.thread = None
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button)

  def osnova(self):
    pass
    # Основной код

  def on_button(self):
    if not self.thread:
      self.thread = SomeThread()
      self.thread.progressed.connect(self.on_progress)
      self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
      self.thread.start()

  def on_progress(self, value):
    self.pBar.setValue(value)
    self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
    self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
    self.movie.start()

  def on_finished(self):
    self.thread.progressed.disconnect(self.on_progress)
    self.thread.finished.disconnect(self.on_finished)
    self.thread = None
    self.movie_screen.setText(" ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  qApp = QApplication([])
  app = App()
  app.show()
  qApp.exec()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
#import time
#import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *

import threading                                            #  +++


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()   
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    progressed = pyqtSignal(int)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def started_gif(self):
        self.started.emit()        

        def finished_gif():    
            self.finished.emit()

        self.osnovaNew()
        finished_gif()    

    def osnovaNew(self):                                   # <--- Это будет наша основная задача 
        for i in range(10000):
            self.progressed.emit(i//100)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1)
        self.progressed.emit(100)  


class GifDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GifDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

        self.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background-color:black; color:white }")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text="Пожалуйста, подождите, \nвыполняется основная задача ...",
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        )
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")   
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_gif(self):
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(
            "D:/_Qt/img/spir.gif",                
            parent=self
        )
        self.label2.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.show()


class SomeThread(QThread):
    progressed = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 6):
            self.progressed.emit(i)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)       # time.sleep(1)

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Потоки")
        self.setFixedSize(900, 500)
        self.pBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pBar.setMaximum(5)
        self.pBar.setGeometry(0, 30, 300, 40)
        self.button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.movie_screen = QLabel("===================", self)
        self.movie_screen.setGeometry(5, 50, 500, 500)
        self.thread = None
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button)
#+++        
        self.pBar2 = QProgressBar(self)                             # + pBar2
        self.pBar2.setGeometry(0, 100, 300, 40)

    def osnova(self):
#        pass
        # Основной код ->>> перенесен в ->>> osnovaNew              # <---
        self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

    def on_button(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        if not self.thread:
            self.osnova()                                           # +

            self.thread = SomeThread()
            self.thread.progressed.connect(self.on_progress)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.thread.start()
#+++            
            self.worker = Worker()
            self.gif_dialog = GifDialog(self)
            self.worker.started.connect(self.gif_dialog.show_gif)
            self.worker.progressed.connect(self.on_progress2)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.w_close)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker.started_gif, daemon=True).start()

    def w_close(self): 
        self.gif_dialog.close()  
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    def on_progress(self, value):
        self.pBar.setValue(value)

#+++        
    def on_progress2(self, value): 
        self.pBar2.setValue(value)

    def on_finished(self):
        self.thread.progressed.disconnect(self.on_progress)
        self.thread.finished.disconnect(self.on_finished)
        self.thread = None
        self.movie_screen.setText("Finish")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication([])
    app = App()
    app.show()
    qApp.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> А как сделать так, чтобы вместо прогресБаров были к примеру запросы. Пока выполняются requests запросы, производится гифка. Выполнение запросов закончилось, гифка вырубается?

Вставляйте в метод `osnovaNew` что хотите и испускайте нужный вам сигнал:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *

import threading                                            #  +++

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer                 #  +++
import requests                                             #  +++


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()   
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    requestsed = pyqtSignal(str)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def started_gif(self):
        self.started.emit()        

        def finished_gif():    
            self.finished.emit()

        self.osnovaNew()
        finished_gif()    

    def osnovaNew(self):                                   # <--- Это будет наша основная задача 
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/"
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
        # все ссылки
        links = [link['href'] for link in soup if link.has_attr('href')]
        for link in links:
            self.requestsed.emit(link)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)            


class GifDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GifDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

        self.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background-color:black; color:white }")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text="Пожалуйста, подождите, \nвыполняется основная задача ...",
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        )
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")   
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_gif(self):
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(
            "D:/_Qt/img/spir.gif",                
            parent=self
        )
        self.label2.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.show()


class SomeThread(QThread):
    progressed = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 6):
            self.progressed.emit(i)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)       # time.sleep(1)

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Потоки")
        self.setFixedSize(900, 500)
        self.pBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pBar.setMaximum(5)
        self.pBar.setGeometry(0, 30, 300, 40)
        self.button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.movie_screen = QLabel("===================", self)
        self.movie_screen.setGeometry(5, 50, 500, 500)
        self.thread = None
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)                             # <---
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(300, 30, 400, 400)


    def osnova(self):
#        pass
        # Основной код ->>> перенесен в ->>> osnovaNew              # <---
        self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

    def on_button(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        if not self.thread:
            self.osnova()                                           

            self.thread = SomeThread()
            self.thread.progressed.connect(self.on_progress)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.thread.start()
#+++            
            self.worker = Worker()
            self.gif_dialog = GifDialog(self)
            self.worker.started.connect(self.gif_dialog.show_gif)
            self.worker.requestsed.connect(self.on_textEdit)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.w_close)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker.started_gif, daemon=True).start()

    def w_close(self): 
        self.gif_dialog.close()  
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    def on_progress(self, value):
        self.pBar.setValue(value)

    def on_textEdit(self, value):                                # < ----
        self.textEdit.append(value) 

    def on_finished(self):
        self.thread.progressed.disconnect(self.on_progress)
        self.thread.finished.disconnect(self.on_finished)
        self.thread = None
        self.movie_screen.setText("Finish")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication([])
    app = App()
    app.show()
    qApp.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> А как из класса App передать в класс Worker переменную? У вас там уже введён сайт вики, а у меня пользователь вводит сайт в QLineEdit (в классе App)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *

import threading                                            #  +++

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer                 #  +++
import requests                                             #  +++


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()   
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    requestsed = pyqtSignal(str)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def started_gif(self, url):                                             # <--- + url
        self.url = url                                                      # <--- +
        self.started.emit()        

        def finished_gif():    
            self.finished.emit()

        self.osnovaNew()
        finished_gif()    

    def osnovaNew(self):    # <--- Это будет наша основная задача 

#        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/"                                   # --- -
        response = requests.get(self.url)                                    # <--- self.url

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
        # все ссылки
        links = [link['href'] for link in soup if link.has_attr('href')]
        for link in links:
            self.requestsed.emit(link)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)            


class GifDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GifDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

        self.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background-color:black; color:white }")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text="Пожалуйста, подождите, \nвыполняется основная задача ...",
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        )
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")   
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_gif(self):
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(
            "D:/_Qt/img/spir.gif",                
            parent=self
        )
        self.label2.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.show()


class SomeThread(QThread):
    progressed = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 6):
            self.progressed.emit(i)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)       

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Потоки")
        self.setFixedSize(900, 500)
        self.pBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pBar.setMaximum(5)
        self.pBar.setGeometry(0, 30, 300, 40)
        self.button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.movie_screen = QLabel("===================", self)
        self.movie_screen.setGeometry(5, 50, 500, 500)
        self.thread = None
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self, placeholderText="Введите URL для вашего запроса") # <---
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(0, 90, 300, 40)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)                             
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(300, 30, 400, 400)


    def osnova(self):
#        pass
        # Основной код ->>> перенесен в ->>> osnovaNew      
        self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

    def on_button(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        if not self.thread:
            self.osnova()                                           

            self.thread = SomeThread()
            self.thread.progressed.connect(self.on_progress)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            self.thread.start()
#+++            
            self.worker = Worker()
            self.gif_dialog = GifDialog(self)
            self.worker.started.connect(self.gif_dialog.show_gif)
            self.worker.requestsed.connect(self.on_textEdit)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.w_close)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker.started_gif, 
                                      args=[self.lineEdit.text()],                    # <---
                                      daemon=True).start()

    def w_close(self): 
        self.gif_dialog.close()  
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    def on_progress(self, value):
        self.pBar.setValue(value)

    def on_textEdit(self, value):                                
        self.textEdit.append(value) 

    def on_finished(self):
        self.thread.progressed.disconnect(self.on_progress)
        self.thread.finished.disconnect(self.on_finished)
        self.thread = None
        self.movie_screen.setText("Finish")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication([])
    app = App()
    app.show()
    qApp.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы вместо прогресБаров были к примеру запросы. Пока выполняются requests запросы, производится гифка. Выполнение запросов закончилось, гифка вырубается?

Comment: @djimbosfan я добавил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы очень сильно помогли. 3 дня искал ответ.

Comment: А как из класса App передать в класс Worker переменную? У вас там уже введён сайт вики, а у меня пользователь вводит сайт в QLineEdit (в классе App)

Comment: @djimbosfan Если мои ответы помогли вам, не забывайте отмечать их как правильные. Если у вам есть другие вопросы, задавайте новый  вопрос.

Comment: Я задал вопрос...  "А как из класса App передать в класс Worker переменную? У вас там уже введён сайт вики, а у меня пользователь вводит сайт в QLineEdit (в классе App)"

Comment: @djimbosfan я добавил ответ