# PyQt5 GUI + Simple Parser

Tags: python, парсер, pyqt5, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь написать простой парсер на BeatifulSoup и подключить к нему Gui на PyQt5. Парсер готов, и все работает как надо, а вот с Gui никак не могу разобраться. Конкретно проблема в связке parser.py и gui.py. (я новичок, поэтому прошу не ругаться за кривой код) Вот код парсера :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

def main():
  i=0
  kl = 0
  n = input('Нужна ссылка? +/- ')
  j = int(input('Сколько страниц отобразить? '))
  baseurl = input('Введите ссылку ')
  while i <= j-1:
    i = i+1
    p = '#p'
    pop = '_popular_desc'
  for kl in range(j):
    kl = kl +1
    prime = p+str(kl)+pop
    url = baseurl + prime
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(0.8) 
    requiredHtml = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requiredHtml, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a' , class_='market_listing_row_link')
    lots = []
    print (' ')
    for item in items:
      lot1 = item.find('span',class_='market_listing_item_name').text,item.find('span', 
class_="market_table_value normal_price").find_next('span' , 
class_='normal_price').text,item.find('div',class_='market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row 
market_listing_searchresult').find_previous('a',class_='market_listing_row_link').get('href')
 lot2 = item.find('span',class_='market_listing_item_name').text,item.find('span', 
class_="market_table_value normal_price").find_next('span' , class_='normal_price').text
     if n == '+':
       print(lot1)

     elif n == '-':
       print(lot2)

 else:
      print('Парсинг окончен')


def proxy():
    pr = input('Хотите использовать прокси? +/- ')
    if pr == '-':
      main()
    elif pr == '+':
      PROXY = input('Введите Прокси ')
      options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

main()
proxy()
input('Введите Enter для выхода ')
```

А вот gui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from parseui import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
import sys
import parser

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ButClick)

    def ButClick(self):
         parser.main()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В parser.py Есть переменные (n , j , baseurl)
Их я хотел бы вводить через графический интерфейс( lineEdit,lineEdit_2 и т.д) но как это сделать не понимаю, ведь в gui.py есть import parser, а значит в parser я уже не смогу прописать import gui.

Comment: я не могу проверить работу вашего примера, т.к. он не воспроизводимый. Но вы можете  глянуть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990825/pyqt5-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/990864#990864 может будет полезно.

Answer (score 1):

В простых случаях. Вернул

```
def main(n , j , baseurl):
   ....
   lots = []
   for item in items:
      ...
      lots.append(lot)

   return lots
```

Принял

```
def ButClick(self):
    n = 
    j = ...
    baseurl = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
    lots = parser.main(n , j , baseurl)
    textArea.setText(str(lots))
```

Но если надо каждую итерацию их обновлять, то нужно передать колбэк функцию

в parser.py

```
def main(cb, n , j , baseurl):
   ....
   while ...
       for ....
           for ....
               cb(lot)
```

... в gui.py

```
def ButClick(self):
     parser.main(self.Update, n , j , baseurl)

def Update(self, lot):
    self.ui.textArea.appendText(lot)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
```

`input()` убираешь, принт меняешь на `cb(...)`

Comment: Тут дело в том что мне в gui.py нужно ввести эти переменные, то-есть как-то взять их из main(), дать им значения в lineEditах в gui, и вернуть обратно.

Comment: построчно чтоль расписать?) функция Update ставит результат на инпуты, вызывается она в парсере, туда она попадает через аргументы

Comment: ай блин... ну называй переменные понормальному..) а то что куда передать не понятно

Comment: переписал ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, пока не понятно, но буду сидеть разбираться)

Comment: поправил ещё чуток...

Comment: Когда создается приложение на qt с графическим интерфейсом, то что во что должно импортироваться? Просто, исправил код, теперь интерфейс не запускается совсем

Comment: main()
proxy()

пусте вызовы убрать нужно

Comment: Только сейчас немного начинаю понимать. lots.append(lot) это полный список найденных элементов, а его еще надо отфильтровать, вот например lot1 = item.find('span',class_='market_listing_item_name').text,item.find('span', 
class_="market_table_value normal_price").find_next('span' , 
class_='normal_price').text,item.find('div',class_='market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row 
market_listing_searchresult').find_previous('a',class_='market_listing_row_link').get('href'), или lot2 в зависимости от значения n. Поэтому должно быть не return lots а lot1 или lot2 опять же в зависимости от n

Comment: да, я не переписываю код за вас, а только указал как исправить - попробуйте переписать код заново, а не исправлять тот что есть

Comment: Очень извиняюсь за надоедливые вопросы, сижу разбираюсь, не понимаю как работает колбэк функция, если не затруднит, можно пожалуйста поподробнее

Comment: Пока что пытаюсь взаимодействовать только с baseurl и cb. Получаю такую ошибку : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'baseurl' referenced before assignment

Comment: def main(cb, baseurl): - так?

Comment: def main(baseurl , cb):
url = baseurl + prime
lot2 = ...
cb(lot2)
return(lot2)

Comment: или cb или ретурн - лучше не смешивать

Comment: Убрал return, ошибка осталась

Comment: module1.main(self.Update, baseurl) baseurl = self.ui.lineEdit.text() местами строчки поменяй

Comment: Теперь ругается на эту строчку : url = baseurl + prime говорит нельзя метод со строкой складывать. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'str'

Comment: def main(baseurl , cb) поменял местами cb и baseurl, вылезла совсем другая ошибка:'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'appendText'. я ниче не понимаю

Comment: Разобрался, нужно вместо appendText использовать просто append()

Answer (score 0):

Пару примеров для демонстрации принципа:

```
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...
    def ButClick(self):
        # Берем значение url из соответствующего компонента вашего GUI
        res = parser.main( self.ui.lineEdit.text(), <другие аргументы>  ) # Так передаем baseurl
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(<Вывод результата парсинга>)

        # Установлена ли галочка Использования прокси
        parser.proxy( self.ui.checkBoxUseProxy.isChecked(), <другие аргументы> ) # Используем ли прокси
        # и так далее
```

Теперь надо добавить соответствующие аргументы в функции и убрать из них input'ы:

```
def main(baseurl):
    ...
    return lot1, lot2

def proxy(use):
    if use:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    return ...
```